# "Первобытное состояние" — каким было значение фразы сто лет назад?

Tags: значение-слов, выбор-слов, история

Встретилась эта фраза в статье Л. Млечина [**"Министр женского счастья"**](http://www.mk.ru/social/2017/11/12/abort-ne-prestuplenie-revolyuciya-ministra-zhenskogo-schastya-aleksandry-kollontay.html) :

*Сохранился «Отчет по столу прессы Комиссариата государственного призрения за второе полугодие 1917 года». Это вырезки из газет о деятельности ведомства Коллонтай. Среди них — напечатанное в прессе распоряжение наркома Петроградской земской управе: «Настоящим предписывается выдавать суточные деньги **уволенным в первобытное состояние** увечным, раненым и больным, а также выздоравливающим солдатам».*

Какое значение имело слово "первобытный" в этом контексте (век назад)?
Возможно, это опечатка или описка. Тогда какое же слово должно быть вместо него?

[В его же книге [**"Стальной оратор, дремлющий в кобуре..."**](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=68373&p=77) отрывок присутствует, только без тире.]

Answer (score 4):

(разг.) Прежний, первоначальный

*(Ефремова. Толковый словарь, 2012)*

Первобытное состояние тогдашнего солдата - рабочий или крестьянин.

**P.S.** В наше время вместо всей выделенной фразы написали бы "**демобилизованным**".